# Dynamic nested master page in ASP.net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got some views that share a master page and I want to programatically set the master page for the master page. Is it possible to do this? How do I get a reference to the master of a master?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 0):

Return layout page file as part of model. and specify the LayoutPage property from the model as follows:

```
 @{
      LayoutPage = ViewBag.LayoutPage;
  }
```

Please refer following link for basic razor layout page concepts

[Layout/Master pages using Razor](http://ultimatetutorial.com/post/razor-layout-masterpages)